# Java Process(Builder) with Unix: cant run program

Tags: java, shell, unix, processbuilder

I want to execute a shell command via Java and tried using ProcessBuilder.class and Process.class:

```
public Process createProcess() throws IOException 
    {       
            List<String> cmds = new ArrayList<>();
            cmds.add("start_date=\"2021-07-04\" && echo \"Starting with startdate=$start_date\""); 
            return (new ProcessBuilder(cmds)).start();
    }
```

When I execute the exact same command on my shell, it works. When I do this in Java I get:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "start_date="2021-06-10" (shorted ...)": error=2, No such file or directory

(I also tried it without the variable start_date by entering the date directly)

Why won't it work? Can I configure somehow, that Java knows that this is not a file etc.?

Comment: ProcessBuilder is not running the commands in a shell. Read the Javadoc for ProcessBuilder. Ask another question if you need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write script in separate .sh file and pass the path of file and any parameter that is need for script execution ( here you may need to pass startDate)

Then you can execute it as below as below

```
   String[] cmd = {"sh","-c",pathOfShellScript+" "+ startDate}; 
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
   pb.command(cmd);
   Process proc = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only Java methods that allow a command as single string are some of the Runtime.exec methods.  And as sanjeevRm pointed out, you would need to explicitly invoke a shell in order to interpret shell syntax like `&&` and `>&` and use of shell variables.

However, you don’t need any of those things.  Java can do all of that.

```
String startDate = "2021-07-04";

File log = new File("/data/DOCKER/test/test.log");

String startMessage = "Starting with startdate=" + startDate;
System.out.println(startMessage);
Files.writeString(log.toPath(), startMessage);

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "docker", "exec", "test", "bash", "-c",
    "cd /prior/ && python3 -m test.app"
        + " --config_path=/data/DOCKER/prior/config.json"
        + " --start_date=" + startDate);

builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo(log));

return builder.start();
```